# How to map a class to a subclass with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

If I have a class:

```
public class MainClass
{
   public string StringA {get; set;}
   public string StringB {get; set;}
   public string StringC {get; set;}
   public string Candy {get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to map that to another class

```
public class NewClass
{
   public string StringA {get; set;}
   public string StringB {get; set;}
   public string StringC {get; set;}
   public CandyObj Candy {get; set; }
}
```

and CandyObj is simply:

```
public class CandyObj 
{
   public string CandyID {get; set;}
   public string CandyName {get; set;}
}
```

How can I handle the mapping of the CandyObj in the NewClass?

I've tried to go this route:

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
    {
        c.CreateMap<MainClass, NewClass>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Candy.CandyID, m => m.MapFrom(a => a.Candy))
            .ForMember(x => x.Candy.CandyName, m => m.MapFrom(a => a.Candy));
    });
```

But I get "Expression 'x => x.Candy.CandyID' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties."

I'm still new to AutoMapper so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I can accomplish by doing this:

```
        c.CreateMap<MainClass, NewClass>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Candy,
                       opts => opts.MapFrom(
                           src => new CandyObj
                           {
                               CandyID = src.Candy,
                               CandyName = src.Candy
                           }
                       ));
```