# Java mapping to parent class

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

I'm struggling to make a mapping from class B to any subclass of A. See code below. It seems it is not possible with ModelMapper, since it ignores converter if it is not exact match. Could you recommend some similar library that is capable of this? Or any recommendation how to do similar behavior, without specifying all possible subclasses explicitly. Thanks a lot.

```
package com.randakm.p2plibrary.service.main;

import org.modelmapper.Converter;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.spi.MappingContext;

public class ServiceMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.addConverter(new B2AConverter());

        B b = new B();
        b.b = "some value";
        A a = mapper.map(b, AA.class);
        System.out.println("a: "+a.a); // I expect this to have the value from b

    }

}

abstract class A {
    String a;
}

class AA extends A {
    String aa;
}

class AAA extends A {
    String aaa;
}

class B {
    String b;
}

class B2AConverter implements Converter<B, A> {

    @Override
    public A convert(MappingContext<B, A> context) {
        B b = context.getSource();
        A a;
        try {
            a = context.getDestinationType().newInstance();
            a.a = b.b;
            return a;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the result you're getting with the current implementation?

Comment: currently result is null, since the converter is not used at all by model mapper.

Comment: you can see this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355951/how-to-map-a-class-to-a-subclass-with-automapper . using automapper https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html